# mise to setup java versions

Tags: java, mise

Hi I am using [mise](https://mise.jdx.dev/lang/java.html) lib to manage & switch between different versions of java. I ran the command

```
mise use java@adoptopenjdk-8.0.402
```

A file `.mise.toml` was created with the following content.

```
[tools]
java = "adoptopenjdk-8.0.402"
```

Then I checked the java version. It still says java 17. I was expecting to see version 8.

I tried equivalent commands for python. I was able to switch between v3.11 and v3.12 seamlessly.

Is there any step that I am missing? TIA.